# C++ : no matching function for call to

Tags: c++, function, reference, iterator, arguments

Sorry for my English.

I defined my own function that compare two maps ( if the input includes the word ) . The problem is , when i use it in the anagram function , i have the error " no matching function for call to compare maps " . I think it's a problem with my arguments , more precisely with iter . here is my function :

```
bool comparemaps(std::map<char, int>::iterator  wordfirst , std::map<char, int>::iterator  wordlast , std::map<char, int>::iterator  inputfirst , std::map<char, int>::iterator  inputlast){

map<char, int>::const_iterator w = wordfirst , i=inputlast;

while(w != wordlast){

    if(i == inputlast || w->first < i->first)
        return false;

    if(w->first == i->first){

        if(w->second > i->second)
            return false;

        else
            w++;
            i++;
        }

    if(w->first > i->first)
        i++;


    }
return true;
}
```

and in the anagram function (not finished):

```
vector<vector<string> > anagrams(const string& input , const Dictionary& dict ,
                             int max){

map<char,int>  inputmap;

fillmap(inputmap, input.begin(),input.end());

for( Dictionary::const_iterator iter = dict.begin(); iter != dict.end() ; iter++){


    comparemaps(iter->letters.begin(),iter->letters.end(), inputmap.begin(), inputmap.end());


       }
```

i think it's a problem with iter->letters.begin() and iter->letters.end() . letters is a map in a structure named word . Dictionary is a vector of word . the header is defined like this ( in hpp file ) :

```
bool comparemaps(std::map<char, int>::iterator  wordbegin , std::map<char, int>::iterator  wordlast , std::map<char, int>::iterator  inputbegin , std::map<char, int>::iterator  inputlast);
```

i'm asking for help ! tell me if you want more information

Comment: how exactly is `Dictionary` typedefed ?

Comment: You should post the entire error message - it also includes the types that don't match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Dictionary` is defined as:

```
typedef std::vector<Word> Dictionary;
```

and `Word` is defined as:

```
struct Word
{
    map<char,int> letters;
};
```

then:

```
Dictionary::const_iterator iter
```

*points* to `const Word`, which implies that `iter->letters.begin()` returns `map<char,int>::const_iterator` which is not convertible to `map<char,int>::iterator` required by your function `comparemaps`.

Change the signature of your function into:

```
bool comparemaps(std::map<char, int>::const_iterator  wordfirst
               , std::map<char, int>::const_iterator  wordlast
               , std::map<char, int>::iterator  inputfirst
               , std::map<char, int>::iterator  inputlast);
```

Comment: Thank you it works ! So a const iterator can't be convert to a iterator ? Thank you very much

Comment: `const_iterator` can't be converted to `iterator` as it would break `const` correctness, though `iterator` is convertible into `const_iterator`

Comment: Sorry if i didn't include all the code but it was my first post and i was busy and i had to go , it will be better next time .

Comment: And why don't we put const_iterator for inputfirst and inputlast ?

Comment: @Nabs you can as well, it is even advised, the problem is I can't see from the code provided what actually happens in your function. Whenever you don't modify values, use `const`